# Dataadapter update with VB

Tags: vb.net, sql-update

I hope some vb expert could tell me what I am doing wrong.
I am trying to open, modify and update a record in Northwind MDF.
The DA.Update(DS)   statement always generate an error.
I find several examples on the net but only in C and thatI dond’t understand, only work in VB. I find myself  so stuppid not to understand the update mechanism.

### My source:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Call GETNWDS()
        ContactNamebox.Text = ContactNamebox.Text + "   " + Now
        Call UpdateNWDS()
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub GETNWDS()
    '' open custumor  DataAdapter daaset DS

    Dim connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NW testConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName FROM Customers where CustomerID='ALFKI'"

    Dim CN As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim DA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, CN)
    Dim DS As DataSet = New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS)
    Dim DT As DataTable = DS.Tables(0)
    Dim row As DataRow = DT(0)

    CustomerIDbox.Text = row("CustomerID").ToString
    CompanyNamebox.Text = row("CompanyName").ToString
    ContactNamebox.Text = row("ContactName").ToString

    CN.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateNWDS()

    Dim connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NW testConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName FROM Customers where CustomerID='ALFKI'"

    Dim CN As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim DA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, CN)
    Dim DS As DataSet = New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS)
    Dim DT As DataTable = DS.Tables(0)
    Dim row As DataRow = DT(0)

    row("CustomerID") = CustomerIDbox.Text
    row("CompanyName") = CompanyNamebox.Text
    row("ContactName") = ContactNamebox.Text

    Textbox.Text = row("ContactName").ToString

    ' DA.Update(DS)  ' skip to avoud error
    CN.Close()
```

### End Sub

The webform is being filled with 3 DB items.
Then 1 box is changed and the update toutineis called but there is an error on the update statement.
Skippimg this statement shows this webform.
Note that the new row value is displalyed in a textbox.

Comment: NEVER tell us that an error occurs without telling us what it is.  The IDE provides you with an error message for a reason.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the same data twice.  When it's time to save, what's the point of retrieving the data again when you already have it?  Edit the `DataTable` that you already have.

Comment: I still stand by my first comment but your issue is so glaring that, in this case, I don't need an error message.  If you want to update the database then you need a SQL `UPDATE` statement.  Where's yours?  If you want one created for you, which is possible in some but not all cases, then you need to use a command builder.  If you don't do that then you need to actually create one yourself.